# e2fsck -n + how to know if need to run e2fsck in order to fix corrupted blocks?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, fsck, e2fsck

we want to check the filesystem on the disks as /deb/sdc  .... /dev/sdg on each linux redhat machine

the target is to find what are the disks that required e2fsck ( as e2fsck -y /dev/sdb . etc )

according to man page

```
-n     Open  the filesystem read-only, and assume an answer of `no' to all questions.  Allows e2fsck to be used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at
          the same time as the -p or -y options.
```

when we run the command ( only example )

```
 e2fsck -n   /dev/sdXX
```

we get

```
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Warning!  /dev/sdc is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sdc: clean, 94/1310720 files, 156685/5242880 blocks
```

so what need to capture from e2fsck output , that required to run  e2fsck ?

**e2fsck process**

```
init 1

umount /dev/sdXX

e2fsck -y /dev/sdXX  ( or e2fsck -C /dev/sdXX for full details ) 

init 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for the output of `tune2fs` rather than `e2fsck`

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdXX |grep "Filesystem state\|Last checked\|Check interval"
```

which should yield something like this:

```
Filesystem state:         clean
Last checked:             Mon Nov 28 16:03:44 2016
Check interval:           31536000 (12 months)
```